# PHP Mail Script Based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: php, html, email

I have a script I acquired through here (Thanks Stack Overflow folks), and I wanted to modify it slightly to fit our specific application.

Application: 
We have an admin panel that I want to slip in a simple alerting form for when they need to reach all (or some) of our team based on severity.

Minor - receives messages from all issues.
Major - receives messages from some issues.
Emergency - receives critical only messages.

Basically, depending on what style of alerts the team member wants to receive, we place their email into the script under those specific sections. Usually, if they're under Minor, they're on all three. If they're under Emergency only, then that's the only thing they're under. We manually put them into the coding. (Unless someone knows how to code it to pull from an SQL database table, but that's okay)

Here's the current script.

```php
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "";   // Receiving Email Address
    $headers = "From: alerts@domain.com" . "\r\n" .
"BCC: " . $_POST['level'] . " ";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = "From:" . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you ";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
form {
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 10px;
}
</style>
<head>
<title>KSI Alerts</title>
</head>
    <select name="level">
        <option value=0 selected>-Alert Level-</option>
        <option value='email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com' name="minor">Minor</option>
        <option value='email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com,email3@domain.com' name="major">Major</option>
        <option value='email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com,leaders@domain.com,all@domain.com' name="emergency">Emergency</option>
         </select> 
<body>

<form action="?db=alertconfirm" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Summary: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
<!--Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br> -->
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A. dont put the addresses in the html, to easy to be scraped, put them in the php. B. dont just ask us to writ the code for you (especially when your just pasting back code from here in the first place)

Comment: We'll I appreciate the feedback. What I'm trying to figure out is how to make the drop-down choose what emails to send to.

Comment: move the select block inside the form, its currently creating invalid html. Then look at the what you get in your post super global.

Comment: Thanks nogad, giving that a shot right now.

Comment: @nogad, that works as intended. Thank you. I'm working on figuring out how to place it into the PHP coding instead as you suggested previously. Is there a way to make the email addresses a specific variable like:

$minor = test@domain.com, test2@domain.com

$major = testing@domain.com

$emergency = emailall@domain.com

And then just use the dropdown to pick the variable that is used in the "BCC" portion?

Comment: your form doesn't need to show emails in the source. The options could be 1,2,3  then check when submitted `if ($_POST['level'] ==1){email to 1@address;}`